# how to check if the php variable containg hindi text

Tags: php, variables, hindi

**like**

```
$a = चौधरी;
$a = abdul;
```

How to check if a have hindi text or english ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for english characters with a simple regex:

```
<?php
$regex = '~^[a-zA-Z]+$~';
$string = 'abdul';
if (preg_match($regex, $string)) {
    echo "All English!";
} else {
    echo "Anything else";
}
```

You could as well use something with `\p{xx}` with `xx` being one of

> Arabic,  Armenian, Avestan, Balinese, Bamum, Bassa_Vah, Batak,
>   Bengali,
>          Bopomofo, Brahmi, Braille, Buginese, Buhid,  Canadian_Aboriginal,  Car-
>          ian, Caucasian_Albanian, Chakma, Cham, Cherokee, Common, Coptic, Cunei-
>          form, Cypriot, Cyrillic, Deseret, Devanagari, Duployan, Egyptian_Hiero-
>          glyphs,  Elbasan,  Ethiopic,  Georgian,  Glagolitic,  Gothic,  Grantha,
>          Greek, Gujarati, Gurmukhi,  Han,  Hangul,  Hanunoo,  Hebrew,  Hiragana,
>          Imperial_Aramaic,     Inherited,     Inscriptional_Pahlavi,    Inscrip-
>          tional_Parthian,  Javanese,  Kaithi,   Kannada,   Katakana,   Kayah_Li,
>          Kharoshthi,  Khmer,  Khojki, Khudawadi, Lao, Latin, Lepcha, Limbu, Lin-
>          ear_A, Linear_B, Lisu, Lycian, Lydian,  Mahajani,  Malayalam,  Mandaic,
>          Manichaean,      Meetei_Mayek,     Mende_Kikakui,     Meroitic_Cursive,
>          Meroitic_Hieroglyphs, Miao, Modi, Mongolian, Mro,  Myanmar,  Nabataean,
>          New_Tai_Lue,   Nko,  Ogham,  Ol_Chiki,  Old_Italic,  Old_North_Arabian,
>          Old_Permic, Old_Persian, Old_South_Arabian, Old_Turkic, Oriya, Osmanya,
>          Pahawh_Hmong,    Palmyrene,    Pau_Cin_Hau,    Phags_Pa,    Phoenician,
>          Psalter_Pahlavi, Rejang, Runic, Samaritan,  Saurashtra,  Sharada,  Sha-
>          vian,  Siddham, Sinhala, Sora_Sompeng, Sundanese, Syloti_Nagri, Syriac,
>          Tagalog, Tagbanwa, Tai_Le, Tai_Tham, Tai_Viet,  Takri,  Tamil,  Telugu,
>          Thaana,  Thai,  Tibetan, Tifinagh, Tirhuta, Ugaritic, Vai, Warang_Citi,
>          Yi.

See [**pcre.org**](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) for more details.

Comment: There are more alphabets in the world than just ASCII and non-ASCII...

Comment: @arkascha: I know :)